# Перезапись свойств базового класса

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

Почему не изменяются унаследованные свойства?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
protected:
    int variable{ 0 };
public:
    void get_variable()
    {  std::cout << variable << std::endl; }
};

class Der1 : public Base
{
protected:
  int variable{ 10 };
};

class Der2 : public Base
{
protected:
  int variable{ 5 };
};

int main()
{
    Der1().get_variable();
    Der2().get_variable();

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
0
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в дочерних классах по 2 переменных `variable` — `Base::variable` и `Der::variable`. И еще потому что  `get_variable()` не виртуальная, так что знает только свой класс. Чтоб было понятнее — посмотрите этот код:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int variable{ 0 };
public:
    void get_variable()
    {  std::cout << variable << std::endl; }
};

class Der1 : public Base
{
public:
    void get_variable()
    {
        std::cout << Base::variable << std::endl;
        std::cout << Der1::variable << std::endl;
    }
protected:
  int variable{ 10 };
};

class Der2 : public Base
{
public:
    void get_variable()
    {
        std::cout << Base::variable << std::endl;
        std::cout << Der2::variable << std::endl;
    }
protected:
  int variable{ 5 };
};

int main()
{
    Der1().get_variable();
    Der2().get_variable();
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю, что компилятор делает неявное приведение к базовому классу в main()

До компиляции:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
protected:
    int var{ 5 };
    
public:
    void out_var()
    {  std::cout << var << std::endl; }
   
};

class Der : public Base
{
protected:
    int var{ 7 };
};

int main()
{
    Der().out_var();

    return 0;
}
```

main() после компиляции:

```
int main()
{
  static_cast<Base &&>(Der()).out_var();
  return 0;
}
```

И да, создаются 2 переменных Base::var и Der::var, каждая в своем классе.

Как вариант:

```
int main()
{
    Der d;
    d.out_var();

    return 0;
}
```

приводится к:

```
int main()
{
  Der d = Der();
  static_cast<Base&>(d).out_var();
  return 0;
}
```